# On the optimality of Stabilizer codes

Tags: research-level, quantum-error-correction

I have been studying about quantum error correction codes, specifically aobut the so-called stabilzer codes, and I wonder if are this class of quantum codes the best codes known (in terms of capacity achieving) yet in the quantum error correction paradigm? If the answer results to be negative, which are the other approaches tested and how better are those in comparison with the stabilizer formulation?

Comment: -1 Not clear, What do you mean by *the best codes known*? What criterion are you using?

Comment: I edited the question to specify. I mean if they are capacity achieving.

Comment: Capacity for what? Optimum, capacity and maximum all mean the same, but they need to apply to something which can be measured.

Comment: Capacity is the maximum information rate achievable over a noisy channel.